# how to store all the values of a list of lists and the frequence of their appearance as well as their index?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, iteration

*my code is this*

```
idnt=[] 
idntfrq=[]           

for i in range(len(occ)):
    idnt.append([])
    idntfrq.append([])
    for j in range(len(occ[i])):
        for j2 in range(j,len(occ[i])):
            for d in occ[i][j]:
                idnt[i].append(d)
                idntfrq[i].append([j])
                occ[i][j].remove(d)
                for d2 in occ[i][j2]:
                    if d==d2:
                
                        idntfrq[i][-1].append(j2)
                        occ[i][j2].remove(d)
```

**I need the number of appearances of each value as well as their indexes**

the list of lists is occ (50 lists inside with various lengths each)

the thought was to iterate over everything,store each value in the idnt[i] list and the
index of the list in which it appears to the idntfrq[i] list and then remove the
element from the list of the current itteration,the occ list should be empty after
that but it is not,i uploaded a prntscr of the occ[0][0] to see what i mean

NOTE: each list inside a list contains every element only once , but i want to count the
occurences across all the lists inside every occ[i] (for i in 50)and also keep the index[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO2eF.png)

Comment: To make your question more understable could you please:
- add an example of input data
- add an example of output
- don't put your text in bold font  
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do what you are asking:

```
mainList = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[1,5,9]]
d = {}
for l in mainList:
    for item in l:
        if item in d.keys():
            d[item] +=1
        else:
            d[item] = 1
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 9: 1}
```

It gives the answer in a dictionary where keys are the items and the values is the number of appearances.

This output and be further formatted if needed.

If you need the indexes of each time a number appears you can simply add a dictionary `di` that has the items as keys and a list of index pairs at which the item appears as the values.

This can be done by adding `di[item].append([idx,jdx])` and `di[item] = [[idx,jdx]]` inside the loop and defining it as `di = {}` before the loop like this:

```
mainList = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[1,5,9]]
d = {}
di = {}
idx = -1
for l in mainList:
    idx += 1
    jdx = -1
    for item in l:
        jdx += 1
        if item in d.keys():
            d[item] +=1
            di[item].append([idx,jdx])
        else:
            d[item] = 1
            di[item] = [[idx,jdx]]
print(d)
print(di)
```

Ouput:

```
{1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 9: 1}
{1: [[0, 0], [2, 0]], 2: [[0, 1]], 3: [[0, 2], [1, 0]], 4: [[1, 1]], 5: [[1, 2], [2, 1]], 9: [[2, 2]]}
```

Comment: is there any way to get the indexes of the original lists in which these values belong as well ? it would be very nice and it would complete my work essentially

Comment: @kyriakoskastriotis yes you can make an index indicator variable `idx` and `jdx` and just update it on each iteration then you can save it however you like.

Comment: Thnx , I'll give it a try :D

Comment: @kyriakoskastriotis awesome, let me know if you get it and if not I can try to help again.

Comment: i dont seem to be able to get it to be sincere , i keep ending up with my original block of code i started with , would you mind to update your answer if its not too much trouble? i would highly appreciate that !!

Comment: @kyriakoskastriotis I don't mind

Comment: @kyriakoskastriotis answer updated, I will also propose an edit to your question.

Comment: thank you very much !!, yes of course , propose an edit

Comment: it worked perfectly!!! ill have to refresh my skills on dictionaries apparently , thanks again for helping!! i trully appreciate that!! bless you!

Answer (score -1):

I think this works:

```py
from collections import Counter
list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
counter = Counter()
for _list in list_of_lists:
    counter.update(_list)
```

Comment: I would happily know why my answer is downvoted, otherwise I can't help finding the solution :)

Comment: i needed to know the frequency of each value inside all lists across all of them and not the frequency of the lists themselves among themselves

Comment: Yes, that's what my code is doing... did you try to run it at least before downvoting it ?

Comment: it wasnt me who downvoted it , my score doesnt allow it anyway